# Show only users that don't yet exist in the through table

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-queryset, django-orm

Inside of the `__init__` method of a form `ProjectUserCreateForm(forms.ModelForm)` to add Users to a Project (Project model has a `users = models.ManyToManyField(...)`) I have

```
self.fields['users'].queryset = User.objects.filter(company=self.request.user.company)
```

This way I'm able to show only the users to be added to the Project that belong to the company of the user requesting the page.

This form can be found in

```
path('<int:pk>/users/create/', views.ProjectUserCreateView.as_view(), name='project-user-create'),
```

where the `<int:pk>` is the PK of the Project, and `ProjectUserCreateView` is a CBV CreateView.

How can I show only the users that belong to the company of the logged in user (this part already works) AND that don't yet exist in the through table (the table based on the ManyToManyField)?

Comment: What is the company to the user? Can you share the relevant models? Can you explain your  question a bit more? You want users that belong to a company, *AND that don't yet exist in the through table* what do you mean by this? From where do you want to fetch them?

Comment: @nigel239 company is a foreign key field in the User model

Comment: @nigel239 the form is to add Users to Projects. I don't want to show as option the users that already belong to that given Project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all users that do not yet belong to the request.user's company with:

```
users_in_company = request.user.company.user_set.all().values(pk).distinct()
users_not_in_company = User.objects.all().exclude(pk__in=list(users_in_company))
```

**Bonus**:
If you want to get all users which don't belong to **any** company:

```
users_not_in_any_company = users_not_in_company.filter(company__isnull=True) # Equal to User.objects.filter(company__isnull=True), but it doesn't really matter.
```

> ### Note:
>
> `request.user.company.user_set.all()`
>
> If you changed the related name of the user to the company, change `user_set` too ofcourse. I could give you the full example code, but alas, no models.

#### Edit:

To get all users in a company if the `request.user` has one:

```
users = request.user.company.user_set.all()
```

To filter those users which belong to a specific project:

```
users.filter(project=my_project)
```

To get users that don't belong to the project:

```
users = User.objects.all().exclude(project__pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

To get users that belong to the `request.user`'s company, but not to a project:

```
request.user.company.user_set.all().exclude(project__pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

---

### Final

```
User.objects.filter(company=self.request.user.company).exclude(project_users=project_pk)
```

Comment: The company users I'm getting with that command. But I wouldn't like all of them because some already belong to that given Project in the through table between Projects and Users.

Comment: By that command I mean `User.objects.filter(company=self.request.user.company)`. But, like I was attempting to explain, that returns as well users that were already added to a Project.

Comment: There is a solution for users without any projects (or companies, model-wise). Please, read the full answer. :) (The code in your above comment, only returns users that belong to that given company. None other)

Comment: that's exactly what I want, except less the ones from that company who were already added to the project

Comment: You're going to have to share some model files. Is there a company and a project model? So you want only users that belong to a company, and a specific project?

Comment: «Is there a company and a project model?», yes, that's correct. The question already mentions what field a project has to identify its users (ManyToManyField)

Comment: You want users that only belong to a project? And not to a company? Or do you want users that belong to a company, but not to a project? Or do you want users that belong to both? Or do you want users that belong to none? What is it you want.

Comment: Users that belong to the company of the logged in user that weren't already added to the Project (the URL identifies the project that we're talking about)

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres Edited my answer. The last solution might be what you need.

Comment: nigel239 it wasn't quite right but the `.exclude` pointed me to the right path. Just updated with the way that I've used